# Web scraping with Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

So I want to obtain the name of each player in all fotball clubs in the Premier League from transfermarkt.
The page I am trying to do for, as a test is: https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/ederson/profil/spieler/238223

I have found the Xpath to be:

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td
```

Keep in mind that I have to use the Xpath due to the structure of the Html code, and that I have to do a For loop for all the players in a club, for all the clubs in the Premier league. I have already obtained the links trough this code:

```
# Create empty list for player link
playerLink1 = []
playerLink2 = []
playerLink3 = []
#For each team link page...
for i in range(len(Full_Links)):
    #...Download the team page and process the html code...
    squadPage = requests.get(Full_Links[i], headers=headers)
    squadTree = squadPage.text
    SquadSoup = BeautifulSoup(squadTree,'html.parser')

    #...Extract the player links...

    playerLocation = SquadSoup.find("div", {"class":"responsive-table"}).find_all("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})

    for a in playerLocation:
        playerLink1.append(a['href'])
        [playerLink2.append(x) for x in playerLink1 if x not in playerLink2] 

    #...For each player link within the team page...
        for j in range(len(playerLink2)):

    #...Save the link, complete with domain...
            temp2 = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk" + playerLink2[j]
    #...Add the finished link to our teamLinks list...
            playerLink3.append(temp2)
```

The links are in a list variable called "playerLink3_u"

How can I do this?

Comment: if you have to use `xpath` then you will have to use `lxml` instead of `BeautifulSoup` which doesn't use `xpath`

Comment: But how do I use it?
Have tried to us lxml, but it does not work. I only get a empty result

Comment: first check if you get this data in HTML - servers may blocks scripts or sends different data. Second: you should manually create shorter `xpath` with classes, id, and elements. And then probably will will know how to get it without using `xpath`.

Comment: BTW: it is unreadable `[playerLink2.append(x) for x in playerLink1 if x not in playerLink2] `> you could write it on normal way. Besides it is in loop in which you add only one element to `playerLink1.append(a['href'])` so there is no need to check again and again other elemenst in `playerLink2`. You could simply check only `a['href']` in `playerLink2`

Comment: This is way to technical for me. I am actually a Business Student with a firm knowledge of Python and Web scraping. Is it another way to do it, which does not require X-number of coding years in experience?

Comment: you could use print() to see what you have in variables. You could use `DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox` to see HTML and check if there are some class names or ID or othere attributes which you could use to get element.

Comment: easy way? There are portals which offer to select element by mouse click and it will get the same element on other pages. But I don't remeber what portals offer it. And it may need money. Authors of framework `scrapy` had portal with something like this

Comment: see [webscraper.io](https://webscraper.io/) - you can use mouse to point element to scrape and it will get it from all pages.

Comment: You can find what you're looking here : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aricht19/Premier-League/master/Data/English%20Premier%20League%20Player%20Info%20(2019_2020).csv Credits to aricht19. Alternatively, scraping from here : http://www.footballsquads.co.uk/eng/2019-2020/engprem.htm should be easier.

Comment: Those links do not have all the info I need. It lacks the agent/agency of the players, which is crucial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how to ge the name with the XPath. You have BS4 imported already so I have written some code to get the player name from the URL you have posted.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request_page = requests.get("http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/ederson/profil/spieler/238223", headers={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.37"})
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(request_page.text, 'html.parser')
player_table = page_soup.find('table', {'class': 'auflistung'})
table_data = player_table.findAll('td')

print('Name: ', table_data[0].text)
print('Date Of Birth: ', table_data[1].text)
print('Place Of Birth: ', table_data[2].text)
```

This will return the name, date_of_birth, and place_of_birth.

Comment: Ok, but how do you find the place of birth then. Because when I tried it, It did not return the Osasco (SP)  Brazil...

Comment: I tried to do the code you wrote. I worked, but when I try to loop it over for example the first 5 links, and append them to a list, it shows the full html code, rather than just the name. Code:

Comment: I've updated my answer to get the date and place of birth also.

Comment: That works. I tried to do it with multiple links in a for loop, and but the results in lists. 
Made a test list with 5 player links. Code:

Comment: #For each player...
for i in range(len(test)):
    #...download and process the two pages collected earlier...
    playerPage = requests.get(test[i], headers = headers)
    playerTree = playerPage.text
    PlayerSoup = BeautifulSoup(playerTree,'html.parser')
    
#...find the relevant datapoint for each player, starting with name...
    tempName = PlayerSoup.find('table', {'class': 'auflistung'})
    t = tempName.findAll('td')
    Name.append(t[0].text)

Comment: Output is a list with the Html code for all 5 players, not the names only. Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Comment: I'm not understanding your original question. I thought you were asking how to get the player name from this webpage: http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/ederson/profil/spieler/238223. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, I wanted first to test it for only one link. Now I want to do the same for multiple links, which are in a LIST, and place them inside a list "Name_list". But when I use the code above, it only gives me the Html code for all the players/links, not the acutal name of the 5 players in the LIST